# Can't set Dropzone options on window.onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, dropzone.js

I'm trying to add [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) to my website but I'm having problem with setting the options when I want. Using jQuery I can run it on `$(document).ready()` like this:

```
<body>
    <form action="/upload" class="dropzone" id="upload-dropzone"></form>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

---

```
//app.js
var Dropzone = require("../vendor/js/dropzone");
$(document).ready(function(){
    Dropzone.options.artworkUploadDropzone = {
        init: function () {
            console.log("init!");
        }
    };
});
```

However, I want to use Dropzone without jQuery and instead set the options on `window.onload`. I've tried the following but the `init` function is not executed.

```
<body>
    <form action="/upload" class="dropzone" id="upload-dropzone"></form>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

---

```
//app.js

var Dropzone = require("../vendor/js/dropzone");
$(document).ready(function(){
    Dropzone.options.artworkUploadDropzone = {
        init: function () {
            console.log("init!");
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/dropzone.js</script>
```

should be:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/dropzone.js"></script>
```

Take a look at http://www.dropzonejs.com/#installation

You should be able to access it via window.Dropzone

Comment: Updated question with `require` instead. Note that the code works with jQuery